# Anaconda 64bit and Pyinstaller: Create exe for 32bit system

Tags: python, anaconda, 64-bit

I use Windows 10 64bit alongside with Anaconda3 64bit. This yields a Python 64bit installation.
With that, I'm creating .exe files using PyInstaller, but obviously, it packs the Python 64bit version into the .exe, so this will NOT run on a 32bit machine.

To make an exe for a 32bit machine, I'd need to use Python 32bit. Is there a way to create a 32bit Python environment alongside my current Anaconda installation? Or would I need to download yet another Anaconda as second installation, which is kinda ugly IMHO?

Thanks!

Comment: Init `Anaconda Prompt`, exec `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1`, this command set a temp env var for current terminal and switch the conda to 32-bit mode, use conda to create a new python env and it will be 32-bit

Comment: Amazing, it works!! :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @alexzshl: Post it as answer, I'll accept it to make this question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. init "Anaconda Prompt"
2. exec `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1`. This command set a temp env var for current terminal and switch the conda to 32-bit mode
3. use conda to create a new python env and it will be 32-bit